# IntelliJ Scala: Package name doesn't correspond to directories structure

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest

I have an existing project in IntelliJ. I have ensured the project conforms to the Maven Standard Directory layout. I have used `g8` to install `sbt`. I have been able to run `sbt` successfully and am now trying to write some tests using `scalatest`.

My `classSpec.scala` cannot see the classes within the rest of the project.

Given the File Structure is as follows:

`~/projects/scala-project/build.sbt`

`~/projects/scala-project/project/build.properties`

`~/projects/scala-project/src/main/scala/class.scala`

`~/projects/scala-project/src/test/scala/classSpec.scala`

Within the `build.sbt` file I have:

```
name := "Scala Project"

organization := "com.examples"

version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4", "2.11.2")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1",
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.11.5"
)

initialCommands := "import com.example.scalaproject._"
```

Does anyone know if this is the issue?

Comment: Where is the `build.sbt` file stored and where is `classSpec.scala` located?

Comment: @PermaFrost thanks for looking. I have added more information to the question to explain where each file lives

Comment: Can you run your tests correctly (with accessing source located in `src/main/scala`) in the `sbt` shell? If that's the case then the problem only exists within IntelliJ and I would re-create the IntelliJ project using IntelliJ's sbt import functionality. Alternatively you could also try the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin that generates IntelliJ projects, but it's not yet fully compatible with IntelliJ 14.x as far as I know.

Comment: Yes I have run `sbt` and then within the sbt shell I have run `~test`  the tests run correctly. When I run `Class c = new class()` I get the following output: `not found: value Class`  (i have replaced specifics in this example with the general terms). I will try your suggestion.

Comment: A new useful error now pops up: `Package name doesn't correspond to directories structure, this may cause problems with resolve to classes from this file` - which describes the issue I am having :)

Comment: So you have a class in package `x.y.z` that's not in a folder `x/y/z` below `src/main/scala` or `src/test/scala`? I actually thought that this is possible with `scalac` but have never tried it out.